# Non singular matrix $M$ such that $MAM^T=F$, normal form

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, jordan-normal-form

Show that there is a non-singular matrix $M$ such that $MAM^T = F$ for any antisymmetric matrix $A$ where the normal form $F$ is a matrix with $2 \times 2$ blocks on its principal diagonal which are either zero or $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1 \\ -1&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

To do so, consider the analogue of the Gram-Schmidt method for antisymmetric matrices using the antisymmetric inner product $\langle x,y \rangle = x^TA y$

I am just really looking for some hints to start. For vectors $x$ and $y$, $$x^T A y = (x_1 \dots x_n) \begin{pmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} &..&A_{1n} \\ ..&..  \\ ..& ..&..&A_{nn} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2\\ ..\\y_n \end{pmatrix}$$ and $A_{ii} = 0, A_{ij} = -A_{ji} $ but I am not seeing how the hint is useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

We suppose that $A$ is written in the canonical basis. Consider the product defined by $\langle x,y\rangle=x^TAy$,  it is a bilinear antisymetric product. There exists a basis $e_1,...e_{2n}$ such that this product in this basis is $e_{n+1}\wedge e_{1}+...+e_{2n}\wedge e_{n}$. The matrix of the bilinear for in this basis is $\pmatrix{0 & 1 \cr -1 & 0}$.

Let $M$ be the transtion matrix from the  basis to $e_1,...,e_{2n}$ to the canonical basis $M^TAM =\pmatrix{ 0 &1\cr -1 & 0}$

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am not sure I understand the proof: 'There exists a basis $e_1, \dots e_{2n}$ such that this product in this basis is ...' What do you mean by the wedge in this context and why is the statement true?  Also, the bilinear product need not be $2 \times 2$ so why is it put equal to the $2 \times 2$ matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ Thanks!

Comment: It the antisymetric product defined by $\langle e_{n+1},e_1\rangle =e_{n+1}\wedge e_1 =1$. You can obtain this basis with Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: I am just to trying to understand why there exists a basis such that the product is $e_{n+1} \,\text{wedge}\, e_1 + \dots $$ and why this particular form of the product is useful? Thanks!

Comment: You can show this recursively consider a non zero vector $e_1,$ there exists $e_{n+1}$ such that $\langle e_1,e_{n+1}\rangle=1$ since the antisymmetric form is not degenerated, $e_{n+1}$ exists. Consider the vector space orthogonal to $Vect(e_1,e_{n+1})$.

Comment: What does $A$ look like in the canonical basis?

Comment: What does the term $e_{n+1} \wedge e_1 + e_{2n} \wedge e_{n}$ evaluate to and why is the matrix $A$ in the basis with which we get the inner product being the above equal to $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}?$$ Thanks!